# How do I add data from parents to child table Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relation

I have 3 tables:

[image]

What I have: 2 pages;

ONE where an admin can add a project's name and the id will be autogenerated and

TWO (currently working on) Add and user with its name, ID to the USERS table, and select a project from the PROJECTS table, so after it gets added, display that info, either the users and the projects they belong to, or the projects and the users it contains.

In this page I am already displaying the projects from the PROJECTS table in a checkbox, since they can belong to several projects, but I need to display: *userName*, *projectName* and probably later the IDs, in a table when they get added.

How can I add that info to the child table and show the columns values from its parents tables? projectName and userName

Any help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

PS: I'm not good with databases so I'm probably missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use userId from "users" table as FK in "projects" table.